# Configure artifactId using variable in OSGi bundle

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix, bnd

I am looking to have a dynamic artifactId in my POM file that builds an OSGi bundle.  I am trying to deploy two instances of a bundle with a slightly different configurations in the same ServiceMix karaf container.

I am using the BND plugin to create the OSGi bundle, but I don't see a configuration in BND that would allow this.

Has anyone been able to dynamically set a bundle name so you can deploy two versions of the same bundle in a single ServiceMix container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to achieve. But to me it looks a lot like you are in need of the ConfigAdmin Service. With the config Admin service you deploy your cfg in the etc folder of  servicemix which is selected to configure a Service. If you want to have multiple instances of one service to be available for every configuration you should look at the ManagedService Factory pattern. It will give you a new Service Instance for every configuration available.